# downloading a file and including it on your project

Tags: jquery

I'm a complete novice and trying to use jquery masonry. What does it mean to download docs and put it in your file?

Can't I just use a cdn? Like with bootstrap we can use a CDN but theres also a option to download bootstrap and use it that way..  Also when they say download the zip file and include it in your file I am somewhat lost. Once I download the file do I literally drag it from my downloads into sublime? This is embarrassing as it seems very simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is where I'm stuck as masonry doesn't seem to be working.

```
Step 1 – Download the masonry.pkgd.min.js file and include it at the end of the page as shown in the following code:
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Masonry Layout with Masonry Plugin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src='masonry.pkgd.min.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You just need to put `masonry.pkgd.min.js` in the same directory as your html.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the file onto your pc:

1. Download the zip file
2. Extract it to a normal file/folder
3. Find your project folder (e.g., the folder 'MyProject' with your index.html file it in)
4. Drag the Masonry file/folder into your project folder, so that it's next to your index.html. This way, your index.html can access the Masonry file/folder.

CDN:

1. Copy+Paste this link into your index.html:
   `<script` `src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.js"`>`</script>`